# Adding Listview items to a table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

New to VBA. 
I'd like to add items from a listview and add into the database.

The table as follows looks like this:

```
Table Student
Autonumber ID
Short Text First_Name
Short Text Last_Name
```

The format of the data is as follows in a listview

```
Smith, John
Doe, John
Doe, Jane
```

I want to iterate over it and then add Smith into the Last_Name and John into the First_Name fields.

My current thought process for how to solve this is:

```
1. Iterate over the listview
2. Convert listview item to a string
3. Split based on the Comma
4. Add into the fields.
```

How would you do this in VBA?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current code attempt.

Comment: Add the ID field as hidden column to the list box, you only ever need to store the ID in your other table, as you can join back to the original table to get all the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints to get you going:

1 -

```vb
With Me.myListView
    For i = 1 To .ListItems.Count
        ' Output goes to Immediate window --> Ctrl+G
        Debug.Print .ListItems(i).Text
        ' .ListItems(i).SubItems(n)  ' if it's a multi-column ListView
```

2 - it's already a string.

3 - `Split()` function in VBA

4 - Recordset (DAO) - `.AddNew` method.